# Get method parameters with specific annotation in aspect in scala using java reflection

Tags: java, scala, reflection, annotations, aspectj

I am using aop in `scala` using `aspectj`. I have a method

```
def delete(@Id id:Long, name:String)
```

How can I get the value of `id` in my aspect file.

```
@Around("execution (* com.myapp.Employee.delete(..))")   
def message(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Object = {    
  val methodSignature =joinPoint.getSignature.asInstanceOf[MethodSignature] 
  //get the value of the field id
  joinPoint.proceed   
}
```

I am not able to get the values.

If I try

```
val res = methodSignature.getMethod.getParameterAnnotations
res.map(annotations => println("size = "+annotations.length))
```

It is always printing the size as 0.

EDIT:
Now I am getting the size correctly. The method was in `object`. But I think there are some problems with java reflection to read `object`. I changed to `class` and now able to get the annotations. But how can I get the parameter which is annotated with that annotation?

Comment: First there are inconsistencies, as in question code the function is named `delete` but the point cut is around `deleteEmployee`.

Comment: @cchantep Sorry, my mistake, issues while copy pasting. I changed it now. But still, I am not getting the names and values correct.

Comment: I would suggest to try with a vanilla Java plain class, to check whether the issue is related to Scala code.

Comment: @cchantep : My main issue is that I do not know how to get the parameter name and value based on an annotation

Comment: I don't think you can get the name or argument, only the arguments list and then its position within.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some Java sample code showing how to get method annotations and also parameter annotations along with paramater types (parameter names are unavailable as *cchantep* already mentioned). I guess you can easily convert it into Scala by yourself.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Before("execution (* com.myapp.Employee.delete(..))")
    public void myAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(joinPoint);
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        String methodName = signature.getMethod().getName();
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = signature.getMethod().getParameterTypes();

        System.out.println("Method annotations:");
        Annotation[] methodAnnotations = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getMethod(methodName, parameterTypes).getAnnotations();
        for (Annotation annotation : methodAnnotations)
            System.out.println("  " + annotation);

        System.out.println("Parameter annotations:");
        Annotation[][] parameterAnnotations = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getMethod(methodName, parameterTypes).getParameterAnnotations();
        int parameterIndex = 0;
        for (Annotation[] annotationsPerParameter : parameterAnnotations) {
            System.out.println("  Parameter of type " + parameterTypes[parameterIndex++].getName() + ":");
            for (Annotation annotation : annotationsPerParameter)
                System.out.println("    " + annotation);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**

Well, in Java 8 there is a [way to determine parameter names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html) if you compile your classes with the `-parameters` option. There is also a compiler switch in Eclipse for that if you use a Java 8 JRE/JDK:

[image: Eclipse compiler settings for Java 8]

You should also use a Java 8-compliant AspectJ version such as the current 1.8.5. Then your aspect can look as follows:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Before("execution(!static * *..Application.*(..))")
    public void myAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(joinPoint);
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();
        Parameter[] parameters = method.getParameters();

        System.out.println("Method annotations:");
        Annotation[] methodAnnotations = method.getAnnotations();
        for (Annotation annotation : methodAnnotations)
            System.out.println("  " + annotation);

        System.out.println("Parameter annotations:");
        for (Parameter parameter : parameters) {
            System.out.println("  " + parameter.getType().getName() + " " + parameter.getName());
            for (Annotation annotation : parameter.getAnnotations())
                System.out.println("    " + annotation);
        }
    }
}
```